# Auto populate Python Generic type for generic subclasses

Tags: python-3.x, generics, typing

I would like to auto populate the type used in a Python derived class from Generic[T]. So something like the following:

```
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar
_T = TypeVar("T")

class A: ...

class B(Generic[_T]):
    TYPE: Type[_T]
    ...

class D(B[A]):
    # I want to TYPE to be auto populated here to be class A given A is already specified as a type parameter
   ...
```

I thought of doing this in __new__ of base class B, it's doable but only sets the TYPE for an instance of class D and seems to be pretty messy:

```
class B(Generic[_T]):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.TYPE = cls.__orig_bases__[0].__args__[0]
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: This is something your type checker should already be capable of automatically inferring. For example, if I ask [mypy](https://mypy-lang.org) what the type of D's type is (e.g. by doing `reveal_type(D().TYPE)`, it'll say it's `Type[A]`. But if you're trying to modify the annotation at *runtime*, well, I'm afraid you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to instantiate an object of "TYPE" in class B during runtime.